# Hello World aka. MNIST with feed forward gets less accuracy in comparison of plain with DistributedDataParallel (DDP) model with only one node

Tags: pytorch, distributed, mnist

This is a cross-post to my question in the [Pytorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/hello-world-aka-mnist-with-feed-forward-gets-less-accuracy-in-comparison-of-plain-with-distributeddataparallel-ddp-model-with-only-one-node/131409).

When using `DistributedDataParallel` (DDP) from PyTorch on only one node I expect it to be the same as a script without `DistributedDataParallel`.

I created a simple MNIST training setup with a three-layer feed forward neural network. It gives significantly lower accuracy (around 10%) if trained with the same hyperparameters, same epochs, and generally same code but the usage of the DDP library.

I created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/joergsimon/mnist-distributed-problem/tree/main) demonstrating my problem.

I hope it is a usage error of the library, but I do not see how there is a problem, also colleges of mine did already audit the code. Also, I tried it on macOS with a CPU and on three different GPU/ubuntu combinations (one with a 1080-Ti, one with a 2080-Ti and a cluster with P100s inside) all giving the same results. Seeds are fixed for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different batch sizes in your two experiments: `batch_size=128`, and `batch_size=32` for `mnist-distributed.py` and `mnist-plain.py` respectively. This would indicate that you won't have the same performance result with those two trainings.

Comment: Oh god, there you play around with your example, and then this happens.... feeling a bit dump again now, but in the end: Thx a lot!